# web scraping : how to scrape one particular table body out of many table bodies?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a particular table in the site - http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/35320.html?class=2;template=results;type=batting

Now, there are multiple tables that are indistinguishable from each other. And I want to scrape only one particular table from there. How do I do that?

I have tried using the `find_all()` function. But that only lists ALL the `<tbody>` tags.

I want to scrape only the highlighted table body.

[image: Screenshot-from-2019-05-31-01-54-52.png]

Answer (score 0):

It is `tbody` tagged and you can use the following css selector with bs4. Then wrap with `table` tags and pass to pandas to print nicely. I'm using bs4 4.7.1

You could also use `table = soup.select('tbody:contains(year)')`.

Python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/35320.html?class=2;template=results;type=batting')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.select('tbody:nth-child(7)')
headers = [item.text for item in soup.select('.headlinks th')]
df = pd.read_html('<table>' + str(table) + '</table>')[0]
df.columns = headers
df = df.dropna(how = 'all', axis=0).drop(['Span',''], axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

df.head()

[image]

Comment: Did you try this?